# Create a matrix in MATLAB with limited number of elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to create an 12*3 matrix in MATLAB that has only 2 non-zero elements in each row. How should I generate a code to get all the possible conditions. The non-zero elements can take on any integers from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the possible combination without repetition for 0 and with repetition for 1 and 2:

```
% Number of integer with repetition.
n = 2

% Generate all the possible combination of 1 and 2.
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n);
M = [zeros(n^2,1),x1(:),x2(:)];

% We shift the 0 column n time.
M = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) circshift(M,x,2),0:n,'UniformOutput',0).');
```

**Result:**

```
M =

   0   1   1
   0   1   2
   0   2   1
   0   2   2
   1   0   1
   2   0   1
   1   0   2
   2   0   2
   1   1   0
   1   2   0
   2   1   0
   2   2   0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if a 24*4 matrix is needed with only two non-zero elements (i.e., 1 and 2). Which means there will be a repetition of zeros.